# How to pass a jQuery selector using apply()?

Tags: jquery

Using apply() is converting a jQuery selector into a DOM element by using the [0] item of the selector array.

I've created an invoke function to call multiple functions all using the same context:

```
function func1(){
    // do something with 'this'...
}

function func2(){
    // something else with 'this'...
}

function func3($msg){
    try{
        alert($msg.text());
    }catch(err){ alert(err); }
}

function invoke(context, funcs, params){
    funcs.forEach(function(func){ func.apply(this, params); }.bind(context));
}

invoke(this, [func1, func2, func3], $('#msg'));
```

[here's the jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/doqm4sf5/3/)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `apply` method expects an array as a second parameter, so this:

```
func.apply(this, [params]);
```

should work as expected. Or you can simply use `call()` instead:

```
func.call(this, params);
```

---

```js
function func1(){
    // do something with 'this'...
}

function func2(){
    // something else with 'this'...
}

function func3($msg){
    try{
        alert($msg.text());
    }catch(err){ alert(err); }
}

function invoke(context, funcs, params){
    funcs.forEach(function(func){ func.apply(this, [params]); }.bind(context));
}

invoke(this, [func1, func2, func3], $('#msg'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="msg">Hello</div>
```

---

https://jsfiddle.net/doqm4sf5/4/

---

Did you want to use `call()` instead?

```js
function func1(){
    // do something with 'this'...
}

function func2(){
    // something else with 'this'...
}

function func3($msg){
    try{
        alert($msg.text());
    }catch(err){ alert(err); }
}

function invoke(context, funcs, params){
    funcs.forEach(function(func){ func.call(this, params); }.bind(context));
}

invoke(this, [func1, func2, func3], $('#msg'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="msg">Hello</div>
```

Comment: Added [params] and it works now, d'oh. Thanks for your answer, sincerely appreciated.